# Detect if Safari user has cards available for Apple Pay

Tags: safari, applepay

According to [Apple Pay JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778000-canmakepaymentswithactivecard) docs, `ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard` should return `true` the device supports Apple Pay and whether the user has an active card in Wallet.

In practice,

```
await ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard('<merchant-id>')
```

returns `true` on Safari both in case has the customer has active cards and in case they don't.

Is there a reliable way to check if the user has cards in the Apple Pay wallet?